# How to define the type in a custom component which wraps @tanstack/react-table?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-table

I can't define a wrapper component with the correct type definition.

Row type:

```
export type Person = {
  firstName: string
  lastName: string
  age: number
  visits: number
  status: string
  progress: number
}
```

defaultData:

```
export const defaultData: Person[] = [
  {
    firstName: 'tanner',
    lastName: 'linsley',
    age: 24,
    visits: 100,
    status: 'In Relationship',
    progress: 50,
  },
  {
    firstName: 'tandy',
    lastName: 'miller',
    age: 40,
    visits: 40,
    status: 'Single',
    progress: 80,
  },
  {
    firstName: 'joe',
    lastName: 'dirte',
    age: 45,
    visits: 20,
    status: 'Complicated',
    progress: 10,
  },
]
```

Custom GridTable:

```
import React from 'react';
import {TableInstance} from '@tanstack/table-core';
import {TableGenerics} from '@tanstack/table-core/src/types';

type Props<T> = {
  table: TableInstance<T>
}

export function GridTable<T extends TableGenerics>({table}: Props<T>) {
  return <div>
    <table border={1}>
      <thead>
      {table.getHeaderGroups().map(headerGroup => (
        <tr key={headerGroup.id}>
          {headerGroup.headers.map(header => (
            <th key={header.id} colSpan={header.colSpan}>
              {header.isPlaceholder ? null : header.renderHeader()}
            </th>
          ))}
        </tr>
      ))}
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      {table.getRowModel().rows.map(row => (
        <tr key={row.id}>
          {row.getVisibleCells().map(cell => (
            <td key={cell.id}>{cell.renderCell()}</td>
          ))}
        </tr>
      ))}
      </tbody>
      <tfoot>
      {table.getFooterGroups().map(footerGroup => (
        <tr key={footerGroup.id}>
          {footerGroup.headers.map(header => (
            <th key={header.id} colSpan={header.colSpan}>
              {header.isPlaceholder ? null : header.renderFooter()}
            </th>
          ))}
        </tr>
      ))}
      </tfoot>
    </table>
    <div/>
  </div>;
}
```

Usage:

```
const table = createTable().setRowType<Person>()

export const defaultColumns = [
  table.createDataColumn('firstName', {
    cell: info => info.getValue(),
    footer: props => props.column.id,
  }),
  table.createDataColumn(row => row.lastName, {
    id: 'lastName',
    cell: info => info.getValue(),
    header: () => <span>Last Name</span>,
    footer: props => props.column.id,
  }),
  table.createDataColumn('age', {
    header: () => 'Age',
    footer: props => props.column.id,
  }),
  table.createDataColumn('visits', {
    header: () => <span>Visits</span>,
    footer: props => props.column.id,
  }),
  table.createDataColumn('status', {
    header: 'Status',
    footer: props => props.column.id,
  }),
  table.createDataColumn('progress', {
    header: 'Profile Progress',
    footer: props => props.column.id,
  }),
]

export const Table: FC = () => {

  const instance = useTableInstance(table, {
    data: defaultData,
    columns: defaultColumns,
    getCoreRowModel: getCoreRowModel(),
  })

  return (
    // FIXME how to define the type of GridTable that I don't need to convert instance `as any`?
    <GridTable table={instance as any}/>
  )
};
```

As you can see, I have to use `as any` to convert the type. If I pass `instance` directly, there will be compilation errors like:

[image]

Could someone help me to define the types correctly?

---

A demo project: https://github.com/freewind/typescript-react-grid-table-demo

Answer (score 0):

Ahh~~ Seems like I was importing wrong types:

**src/GridTable.tsx**

```
// import { TableInstance } from "@tanstack/table-core";
// import { TableGenerics } from "@tanstack/table-core/src/types";
import {
  TableInstance,
  TableGenerics,
} from "@tanstack/react-table";
```